# Connection to Mysql error (111)

Tags: mysql, networking

I have tried it all to connect remotely to my mysql db remotely but I am getting the connection refused error. I have changed the bind-address to 0.0.0.0, I have ran ufw and the output is

```
sudo ufw status verbose
sudo: unable to resolve host iot
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
3306                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
3306                       ALLOW IN    0.0.0.0
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
3306/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
3306/tcp (MySQL)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
3306/tcp                   ALLOW IN    0.0.0.0
3306 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
3306/tcp (MySQL (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

3306/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

I have allowed for my ip to be granted privilege and also nothing :

```
mysql> select host, user from mysql.user;
+----------------+-------+
| host           | user  |
+----------------+-------+
| %              | admir |
| %              | root  |
| 127.0.0.1      | admir |
| X.X.X.X        | admir |
| X.X.X.X        | root  |
| localhost      | admir |
| localhost      | root  |
+----------------+-------+
```

Can someone please tell me if there is anything I am missing ? 
It seems that my ip address is not address being broadcasted (only localhost)since :

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3199/mysqld
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried commenting out the bind-address line completely and restarting MySQL? According to that netstat line, you're only listening on the localhost.

Also, make sure that your MySQL processes are truly dead before restarting mysqld, I've seen "ghost" instances of MySQL running in the past that disallowed the service to bind properly and listen for remote connections.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but the netstat line, the output is still the same. I don't know where I am going wrong with this. I have tried everything.